# validations for regular expression with numbers only and it should not allow spaces and letters

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a text box which accepts CVV code of 3 or 4 numbers  and im using regular expression validator 
this is wat im using : is this correct way of using or not

code : ValidationExpression="(\d{3,4}$"

Can anyone help me on this

Regards,
smartdev

Answer (score 2):

That one should, to my opinion generate an error because you are not closing the group capture, at least that is what I think.

`\d{3,4}` should do the trick

\d{3,4} means that you are matching a minimum of three and a maximum of 4 digits. Maybe this [introductory](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) tutorial will do the trick.

Comment: hey npinti , i used this ValidationExpression="^\d{3,4}$" and it worked . thanks again .

Comment: If it worked then you might consider marking my answer as correct :)